# Tikzcd error - narrowed down to one particular cell

Tags: tikz-cd

I tried to run below but I keep getting below error. Let me know if you can spot anything. The arrows coming out of U \times F seem to be the issue, since without any of those arrows, the diagram runs fine but putting in any of them with or without their labels runs me into errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        
        \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=scriptsize]
            
            E' \arrow[r, "\tilde f"] \arrow[d, "\pi'"] & E \arrow[d, "\pi"] && U \times F \arrow[l, "\phi^{-1}"] \arrow[dl, "\pr"] \arrow[r, "\pr_2"]  &&&F \\
            
            X' \arrow[r, "f"] & X && {} &&& {}
            
        \end{tikzcd}
        
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

```
Overfull \hbox (12.25192pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--38
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 We see im-me-di-ately that each col-umn is or-thog-o-nal to $
(\OML/cmm/m/it/10 x[]; []  ; x[]; []\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 )$
[2] [3] [4]

! Package pgf Error: No shape named `tikz@f@2-1-3' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
l.70 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-4.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }
                                                  
l.72 \end{tikzcd}
```

?

Comment: There are several errors. -not easy to know what you want or how you got this far without compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]
E' \arrow[r, "\tilde f"] \arrow[d, "\pi'"] & E \arrow[d, "\pi"] & & U \times F \arrow[l, "\phi^{-1}"] \arrow[dl, "pr"] \arrow[r, "pr_2"]  & & & F\\            
X' \arrow[r, "f"] & X & & & & &              
\end{tikzcd}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Commutative diagram]

Comment: I was using & signs like in the align environment . . . thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're jumping too much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\newcommand{\pr}{\mathrm{pr}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
  E' \arrow[r, "\tilde f"] \arrow[d, "\pi'"] &
  E \arrow[d, "\pi"] &
  U \times F \arrow[l, "\phi^{-1}"'] \arrow[dl, "\pr"] \arrow[r, "\pr_2"]  &
  F \\
  X' \arrow[r, "f"] & X
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

For the middle top arrow, I swapped the position by adding `'` after the label. The column sep seemed too small, you may also want to increase the row sep.

[image]